# Why does my bike feel slow, hard to ride and wobblier now?

Tags: mountain-bike, tire, commuter, balance

I have a mountain bike with road tires, which I've use for commuting almost every day for over a year now but had barely used for the many years before. It has recently (~1.5 months ago) been serviced, which involved the brakes being adjusted and something being replaced due to damage which I believe was the headset, but I can't be sure because I just agreed to replace what was necessary and the conversation was not in my native language.

Before the service my bike was always a bit wobbly, but I always thought it was normal. Afterwards I realised why other people have to make so much less effort to balance when making hand signals.

At some point after the service my front tire seemed to be going down very quickly, but after checking for punctures and finding nothing I put the tube back in and the tire has held pressure well since. The problem is, since then I feel like I am constantly cycling with a flat despite the pressure being right, and my bike seems wobblier than ever before. I don't know whether I did something wrong when I checked the tire (never done it before) or whether it is something completely different.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to bicycles.SE!  So you have a problem with your bike feeling wobbly, and possibly a problem with the tire.  It might help if you edit your post to include a picture of your bike.  If you hold the front wheel with your legs and try to twist the handlebars, can you feel the handlebars moving compared to the wheel?  If you have a tire pressure gauge, what is the pressure, and what is the maximum pressure printed on the tire?

Comment: Assuming your tire pressure is the same as before, and the shop did a reasonable job with the bike, my guess would be that there's some change in the stiffness of the front shock (possibly it was locked out before but not now).  But it's hard to say with any certainty, given the vagueness of your description.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't got and have no means to take a picture. Holding the front wheel and twisting handlebars as you described I think I could feel movement. I tried several times because I wasn't sure if I just wasn't gripping the wheel tightly enough but last try I was fairly certain. Max pressure is 51 PSI, which is what I aim for with the pump but am guilty of sometimes going over "for good measure". When just checked the front tire was between 40 and 50, rear tire was ~50. The gauge doesn't give a reading until I start pumping, so hard to know where it was exactly.

Comment: When you say you "feel movement", what's moving?  Is it the handlebar relative to the fork, or are the shocks waggling back and forth?  (And another thing you want to try is to lock the front brakes and push the bike forward and backward, to check for play in the headset bearings.)

Comment: When you say it's wobbly, what wobbles? Does some part of the bike move, or is the whole bike wobbling about?

Comment: I bet your forks were locked out before, and now they're not. Is there a "lock" lever on the forks?

Comment: @DanielRHicks movement was like handlebars etc. were moving a bit left/right despite wheel being held still, making it seem a bit as though the wheel moved in the opposite direction to the handlebars. I tried pushing back/forth with brakes on but didn't notice anything.

Comment: @andy256 by wobbly I mean going straight ahead requires more concentration/effort than usual, if I just cycled I'd be all over the path.

Comment: @stib I can't see a "lock" lever. My bike is well over a decade old and probably cheap if that helps? Won't be able to add detail for a couple of days but I appreciate the help so far.

Comment: I have a bad feeling about this. It could be that some part of the frame or forks have developed a crack. I *strongly* recommend going back to the shop and getting the bike thoroughly checked. Don't ride it until the problem is fixed.

Comment: Maybe the forks weren't working and they've fixed them. The symptoms you describe sound exactly like the experience of riding with front suspension when you're not used to it.

Comment: When you put the wheel back in, did you make sure it was set into the fork evenly and that the quick release was tightened? It sounds to me like the wheel was replaced crooked or the quick release isn't tight enough.

Answer (score 2):

If your headset was replaced due to crash damaged, well that's a pretty intense crash. I'm going to assume they adjusted it. They also adjusted your brakes. My guess is your problem is two fold:

1) The headset is adjusted too tight, making the bike feel like you have too put too much input into it to turn, and when it does it happens all at once. That would give a wobbly feeling.

2) Check to make sure your brakes are not touching the rim, nor are too close to the rim (less than 3 mm from rim to braking surface). The drag will make you feel like you are constantly pedaling harder.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

There are loads of things to check for looseness in the front end.
At the wheel end, it could be wheel bearings or even the wheel not in the drop outs correctly. Check that the front wheel is spinning well, also when the wheel is tight in the drop outs that it is not moving from side to side. Those could be bearing issues.
At the headset, and you didn't say if it was threaded or threadless, but it could be overly tight or not tight enough. Replacing the headset would be a fairly big repair, more than likely they replaced the bearings (either loose ball or in the capture ring) and then loaded it with grease and put it all back together. Definitely get it checked by a mechanic before riding it again...